# Renaming a folder in Python

Tags: python

Ive successfully made a script which changes all $ to # in a directory, but it doesnt affect the foldername. So the foldername still remains the same name.  How can I modify this to change the $ to # in the foldername as well?

```
def cleanFiles(self):
    directoryChosen = self.directoryChoice()
    print directoryChosen + "     you made it to files selected"

    #for file_names in os.listdir(directoryChosen):
        #self.listWidget.addItem(file_names)

    for n in os.listdir(directoryChosen):
        print n + "   made it here"
        self.listWidget.addItem(n)
        if os.path.isdir(directoryChosen):

            print directoryChosen + "   almost there"
            newname =  n.replace('$', '#')
            print newname + "    this is newname"
            if newname != n:
                print newname
                print n
                path = os.path.join(directoryChosen + '/' + n)
                print path
                target = os.path.join(directoryChosen + '/' + newname)
                print target
                os.rename(path, target)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem you have is that you are doing this:

`if os.path.isdir(directoryChosen):`

When you want to do this:

`if os.path.isdir(n):`

So, with that in mind, inside your loop you actually want to reference `n`, which are the folders and files you are trying to check.

The second problem that you have is in your usage of `os.path.join`.

You don't have to join the way you are joining. You don't need to add the slash between the two, the join does that for you. I suggest reading the doc on that. So you want this:

```
path = os.path.join(directoryChosen, n)
target = os.path.join(directoryChosen, newname)
```

So, the code will then end up looking something like this:

```
for n in os.listdir(directoryChosen):
    print n + "   made it here"
    self.listWidget.addItem(n)
    if os.path.isdir(n):

        print directoryChosen + "   almost there"
        newname =  n.replace('$', '#')
        print newname + "    this is newname"
        if newname != n:
            print newname
            print n
            path = os.path.join(directoryChosen, n)
            print path
            target = os.path.join(directoryChosen, newname)
            print target
            os.rename(path, target)
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91526/discussion-between-idjaw-and-eddwinn).

Answer (score 1):

```
if os.path.isdir(directoryChosen):
    for n in os.listdir(directoryChosen):
        self.listWidget.addItem(n)
        newname =  n.replace('$', '#')
        if newname != n:
            path = os.path.join(directoryChosen, n)
            target = os.path.join(directoryChosen, newname)
            os.rename(path, target)

    newdir = directoryChosen.replace('$', '#')
    if directoryChosen != newdir 
         os.rename(directoryChosen, newdir)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understand your problem correctly. But, you can use the code below:

```
import os

def cleanFiles():
    directoryChosen = "C:\\Test$234"
    if os.path.isdir(directoryChosen):
        for n in os.listdir(directoryChosen):
            newname =  n.replace('$', '#')
            if newname != n:
                path = os.path.join(directoryChosen + '/' + n)
                target = os.path.join(directoryChosen + '/' + newname)
                os.rename(path, target)

    os.rename(directoryChosen, directoryChosen.replace('$','#'))
```

It renames your chosen directory as well, if that is what you are looking for.